# jQuery preventDefault not prevent anchor's behaviour

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I have a menu that filters through categories and hides or displays whatever category is clicked on. The filtering is working fine but for some reason I can't stop the anchor's default behaviour. The anchor has a '#' and every time it is clicked it takes you to the top of the page which is no good UX. I need it to stay where it is so that filtering happens without moving the user to the top of the page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Here is my jquery:

```
$(".portfolio-nav li:first-child").addClass("active");
//Filter through Categories
$(".portfolio-nav ul li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Add class active to the nav item
    $(".portfolio-nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    //Get the filter data
    var filter = $(this).data('filter');
    //set 'All' filter value
    if(filter == '*'){
            filter = 'category';
    }
    //Hide all categories
    $(".categories").children("div").not('.'+filter).css({'width':'0', 'height':'0', 'opacity':'0', 'padding':'0', 'margin':'0'});
    //Fade In filters after categories fade out
    $(".categories").children('.'+filter).css({'width':'48%', 'height':'300px', 'opacity':'1', 'padding':'0', 'margin':'1%'});
});
```

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="portfolio-nav block row">
    <ul class="inline center block">
        <li class="pills slow">
            <a href="#" data-filter="*">
                All
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="pills slow">
            <a href="#" data-filter="websites">
                Websites
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="pills slow">
            <a href="#" data-filter="ecommerce">
                E-Commerce
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="pills slow">
            <a href="#" data-filter="apps">
                Apps
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="pills slow">
            <a href="#" data-filter="tools">
                Tools
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is any of the other JavaScript executing in that handler for you? It's working fine in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qJJK5/)

Comment: Wow! I dont get it. Why would it not work on the site. Everything else is working, is just those anchors that take you to the top. Try the website you'll see what I mean. vallgroup.com on portfolio, right under the laptop (you'll see what I mean). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try my solution ?

Comment: Hey tcj, I did, and it works! Thanks. I am still trying to figure out why it wouldn't work properly with just the jQuery. Have you ever had this happen before? I hate it when The issues or bugs stay unresolved.

Comment: Yes, and I figured out this fix works fine so I always use it when I need it, can you thumb up my answer below so it will help some other devs that might have the same issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this piece of code on line 93 of main.js was causing the anchor tag to jump to the top of the page:

```
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    if(!a[i].onclick && a[i].getAttribute("target") != "_blank") {
        a[i].onclick=function() {
        window.location=this.getAttribute("href");
        return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Change the click handler to not set the `window.location` for an essentially blank `href`:

```
a[i].onclick=function() {
    if(this.getAttribute("href") !== '#') {
        window.location=this.getAttribute("href");
        return false; 
    }
}
```

And you'll be good to go!

Comment: Oh Man!! Thank you very much! You are right. I have been going through the code over and over and kept missing that. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @user3324581 Sure thing =D. Please accept the answer when you get a chance and good luck coding!

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this, you put **#a** (href="#a") or whatever letter you want after the **#** and it won't take you to the top of the page when you click it.