# .preventDefault and return false both not working

Tags: jquery, html

EDIT: I have already searched through the previous questions for solutions, none of which are working. please stop marking as duplicate.

I have a one-page scroller website that uses jQuery animation to scroll down to divs on click, but neither `preventDefault` or `return false` are working to prevent the default action from occurring, so instead of scrolling it's just flashing straight to the sections.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 1500)

    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<nav>                   
    <a href="#aboutUs" alt="About Us Button">About Us</a>               
    <a href="#services" alt="Services Button">Services</a>              
    <a href="#blog" alt="Blog Button">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contactUs" alt="Contact Us Button">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#contactUs" class="button" alt="Enquire Now Button">Enquire Now</a>                
</nav>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery preventDefault not prevent anchor's behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993321/jquery-preventdefault-not-prevent-anchors-behaviour)

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/s61jcd83/. Check the console for errors elsewhere in your code

Comment: you sure you loaded the jQuery library? Looking at your console should show you an indication if it isn't.

Comment: @nickck15 have you checked the console yet? The only reason my code would work and your not is due to an error caused by some other part of your code

Comment: No errors in the console. Only got one warning saying 'jQuery.browser is deprecated'. Done some searching but still unsure as to what that actually means. If it helps I have a live version of the site at nickcookweb.co.uk/test.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
            //this "e" perameter is required to stop the default behaviour
            //but even by default if the "a" tag has a # in its href attribute, 
            //the link will not load or redirect

            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash;
            var $target = $(target);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
            }, 1500);

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this method as explained in OP, doesn't work